# How to get into BIOS when USB keyboard is not powered and have no PS/2 ports?

Tags: boot, bios

Just got a new Windows 7 PC (64-bit) with an Intel DH67CL motherboard.  It's been working fine but I decided I wanted to try to get into the BIOS.  Unfortunately I can't do it because my USB keyboard isn't powered up on boot.

I've tried 3 different keyboards and almost all of the USB ports with no luck.

Any idea how to get into the BIOS?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well as soon as I got my question typed in I figured it out, at least for this Intel motherboard.

I found another computer with the same motherboard and browsed the BIOS settings.  Under Boot/Fast Boot/USB Optimization I found this descriptive text (nowhere in the manual by the way):

"If Enabled, USB devices (keyboards and drives) will not be available until after OS boot, but BIOS will boot faster.  If Disabled, USB devices will be available before OS boot, but BIOS will boot slower.  This question does not affect USB capabilities after OS boot.  This question cannot be enabled while a User Password or Hard Drive Password is installed.  In order to disable Fast Boot without entering BIOS Setup: Power down the system, then hold down the power button until the system beeps."

I tried it, heard 3 beeps, then it booted to a screen saying that the Fast-boot trigger had been detected, would I like to enable fast-boot on the next boot.  No!!  Noticed that my keyboard light was on and hit 'N'.  It rebooted again and I was able to hit F2 to get into the BIOS.

Comment: My question is why would anyone want this enabled in the first place. Seems to be a security feature to keep users out of the bios. Thanks for the info, screenshot of the bios page and description would be nice

Comment: Maybe if you're really concerned with bootup speed, but definitely not a good default setting.

Comment: Sometimes my Nuc doesn't produce a beep, so I count 3 seconds while pressing.

Comment: @Moab It seems the `USB Optimization` setting does have a purpose, even if it was not designed with this use-case in mind: https://superuser.com/a/1664810/122072

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget the oldest trick in the book:

Take out the lithium battery for a few minutes, and then turn on the system.

Comment: Doesn work with laptops and tablets (cause you may lose warranty).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the computer can use USB keyboards in the BIOS and the default BIOS config does that - however a custom configuration caused the keyboard to be ignored.  If you think this is the issue - you can reset **all** your BIOS settings by reverting to their default values using the CLR_CMOS button/jumper.  See: https://superuser.com/a/1095663/100736 .

**WARNING: Don't do that if you do not know what this means or afraid to lose custom settings!**

Comment: That shoukd RESET all settings. Now how is OP going to enter correct (non-default) values without a normal PS2 style keyboard?

Comment: Good point.  I have edited my answer.

Answer (score -4):

1- restart your computer
2- press Delete button on keyboard so the CMOS setup utility screen will show up
3-chosse the third option (integrated peripherals)
4-another screen will show up then choose (**USB keyboard support**:turn it to **enabled**)
5- now press F10 to save it

see this link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qWtkO1yO4Y

Comment: How does the OP press the Delete button without a working keyboard?

Comment: @user269585 - If you are going to answer a question that already has an accepted answer its always good to make sure your answer is even possible to do.  The user had disabled USB devices until the OS booted thus your suggestion is invalid.

Comment: I know it does not seem to answer the question but that is exactly what has helped me solve it. My keyboard was working to get into the BOOT menu or CMOS setup but stopped working in the BOOT menu so that I couldn't select anything.